# Inverse image and linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let **F** : $ R^5 $ —-> $ R^3 $ such that 
$ F_a $ = $ ( x+y+z+2t-au , az-t -u, x+y+(a+1)z+a^2t ) $
The associated Matrix  **A** in row echelon  form
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & a \\
    0 & 0 & a & -1 & -1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & a^2-1 & 1-a \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$ 
The **Q**uestion is : 
For which value of **a** we have $ f^- = (a,1,0) $ is not empty ? 
What does this question mean and when the $ f^- $ is $\emptyset$ and when it is not ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the symbol $f^-$?

Comment: Inverse image ( pre-image )

Comment: How is $f^-$ related to the matrix $A$? Do we just want to solve $Ax=(a,1,0)^T$?

Comment: You need to find some vector $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)^t$ such that $$\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & a \\
    0 & 0 & a & -1 & -1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & a^2-1 & 1-a \\
    \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5 \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} a \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @Azif00 Thanks you , but in case ,for example $f-$ is empty what can i do ? ( not related to this question )

Comment: Then $Ax=b$ has no solution. Why is this a problem?